# Unable to open a file on boot application

Tags: raspberry-pi, ld, beagleboneblack, plc, codesys

I am using beagle bone black (very similar to Rasp pi). I created an program to open a file and read temperature readings from it. It works fine when I run the code manually in the Codesys IDE.  However when I create a boot application and restart my Beagle bone, the file is not opening.

This is the path to the file:   /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-44260f1e64ff/w1_slave

The file I am trying to open is also from a boot application (One-wire temp sensor).
link shows how i created one-wire boot app: http://klaus.ede.hih.au.dk/index.php/BBB_and_OneWire
Thanks.

Comment: could there be a r/w permission problem?

Comment: Hi, Guiorgy, I didn't think about that. do you have any suggestions to solve it?